# MAUI (Android) SurfaceView

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I need a `Android.Views.SurfaceView` component to draw on.
I placed a `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BoxView` component then tried to reach it's platform object using 
 `var platformHandler = compname.Handler.PlatformView;` but I receive `Android.Views.View` which doesn't have/relate a `Android.Views.Surface` object like I need.

Is there any component with a `SurfaceView` or `Surface` 'related' object I can use?
Maybe a way to extract a `Surface` object from the `Android.Views.View`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `.NET MAUI` is a cross-platform framework for creating native mobile and desktop apps with C# and XAML, you can try to use `Microsoft.Maui.Graphics` to achieve this.

.NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) graphics, in the `Microsoft.Maui.Graphics` namespace, enables you to draw graphical objects on a canvas that's defined as an `ICanvas` object.

The .NET MAUI `GraphicsView` control provides access to an `ICanvas` object, on which properties can be set and methods invoked to draw graphical objects. For more information about the `GraphicsView`, see [GraphicsView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/graphicsview).

For more information, please check: [Draw graphical objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/draw).

Besides, `.NET MAUI` graphics includes the ability to paint graphical objects with solid colors, gradients, repeating images, and patterns.
The `Paint` class is an abstract class that paints an object with its output. Classes that derive from Paint describe different ways of painting an object.

For more information, please check:[Paint graphical objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/paint).